# Powershell Commands

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have figured out how to add active directory groups to a user using the following command

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group Name" -Members "UserName"
```

Is there a way to add multiple groups to a user or multiple users to a group? I have tried comma separating the users and groups but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The `Members` parameter can take an array of users, as long as you give it the DistinghuishedNames, SamAccountNames, GUIDs or SIDs

Comment: `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group Name" -Members "UserName1", "UserName2", "UserName3"` does work. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Yeah it works on the users, is there anyway to do the same for multiple groups? It appears that comma separating doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get-aduser username | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf "group1","group2"
```